# Extract all words with @ symbol from a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to extract all @usernames from a string(for twitter) using rails/ruby:

```
String Examples:
"@tom @john how are you?"
"how are you @john?"
"@tom hi"
```

The function should extract all usernames from a string, plus without special characters disallowed for usernames... as you see "?" in an example...

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: what would you expect for `"@user?name"`?

Comment: I've created a seemingly robust regex `/(?<=\s|\A)(@\w+)(?=\,|\?|\s|\.\s)/`. [See here for a demo on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/GlbPCtMSHE). I can't seem to get it to work with Ruby `match` or `scan` so am not submitting as an answer, any takers welcome.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, along with "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Without an example of your code it looks like you want us to write a solution for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: thanks for showing the way @theTinMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Why can't I register certain usernames?](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299)":

> A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z, numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above. Check to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols, dashes, or spaces.

The [`\w` metacharacter is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes):

> `/\w/` - A word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Simply scanning for `@\w+` will succeed according to that:

```
strings = [
  "@tom @john how are you?",
  "how are you @john?",
  "@tom hi",
  "@foo @_foo @foo_ @foo_bar @f123bar @f_123_bar"
]

strings.map { |s| s.scan(/@\w+/) }
# => [["@tom", "@john"],
#     ["@john"],
#     ["@tom"],
#     ["@foo", "@_foo", "@foo_", "@foo_bar", "@f123bar", "@f_123_bar"]]
```

Comment: sorry for the lag. This answer fits best for my script and situation! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it - here's one way:

```
string = "@tom @john how are you?"
words = string.split " "
twitter_handles = words.select do |word|
  word.start_with?('@') && word[1..-1].chars.all? do |char|
    char =~ /[a-zA-Z1-9\_]/
  end && word.length > 1
end
```

The `char =~` regex will only accept alphaneumerics and the underscore

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    @              # match character
    [[[:alpha:]]]+ # match one or more letters
    \b             # match word break
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

"@tom @john how are you? And you, @andré?".scan(r)
  #=> ["@tom", "@john", "@andré"]
```

If you wish to instead return

```
 ["tom", "john", "andré"]
```

change the first line of the regex from `@` to

```
(?<=@)
```

which is a *positive lookbehind*. It requires that the character `"@"` be present but it will not be part of the match.